# Twitter Api Follow

Tags: twitter

I created a sample application in which the user who has Consumer Key, Auth Token, Auth Secret etc information can send message, Follow, UnFollow. For the User I am going to follow. I don't know the aforementioned information. So Far it is good, and Working.

**Question** : Does the Twitter API give the provision to follow authenticated User. Can I make a user whose credentials I don't know follow the Authenticated User?

Comment: I meant, Can I follow that user whose credentials I don;t know and Can I Follow somebody using my token and the user going to bollow somebody, I don;t know his credentials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variables `consumer_key`, `consumer_secret` are set at application level, while `auth_token` and `auth_secret` are user specific.

So if you ask whether an authenticated user can make other user follow him, answer is **NO**.

But if you ask about whether your **application** can make someone's account do something, answer is **YES** provieded it is [authorized](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/authorizing-request) to do so by that [particular someone](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/obtaining-access-tokens).